# spring data mongodb: how to set default value for entity?

Tags: kotlin, spring-data-mongodb

We have document in mongodb db

```json
{_id: xxx, my_field: null}
```

and spring-data-mongodb entity:

```kotlin
@Document
class Test () {
    @Id
    open var id: ObjectId = ObjectId()

    @Field("my_field")
    var my_field: Boolean = false
}
```

It worked on the spring 2.x, but after update up to 3.x it now leads to an errors like:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Number.intValue()" because the return value of "sun.invoke.util.ValueConversions.primitiveConversion(sun.invoke.util.Wrapper, Object, boolean)" is null
    at java.base/sun.invoke.util.ValueConversions.unboxBoolean(ValueConversions.java:108) ~[na:na]
```

It is possible to return old behavior?
(without updaing collection, it's difficult now)